# Run Spark or Flink on a distributed file system other than HDFS or S3

Tags: apache-spark, apache-flink

Is there a way to run Spark or Flink on a distributed file system say lustre or anything except from HDFS or S3.

So we are able to create a distributed file system framework using Unix cluster, Can we run spark/flink on a cluster mode rather than standalone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use file:/// as a DFS *provided every node has access to common paths*, and *your app is configured to use those common paths for sharing source libraries, source data, intermediate data, final data

Things like lustre tend to do that and/or have a specific hadoop filesystem client lib which wraps/extends that.